# How to disable EditText auto suggestion when only TESTING by Espresso in Android

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

What I want

- when real, use auto suggestion
- when testing, do not use auto suggestion because the suggestion view make testing trouble I think.

  - I just want to know the way using `typeText()`
  - when use `replaceText()`, it' ok.

For testing,I used to set inputType like this, but It doesn't work.

```
const val emailInputType =
        InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or 
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS or 
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS

editText.inputType = emailInputType
```

I guess, there is a way to set build.gradle(.app)

Is there a way to do My job(hide edittext auto suggestion when focusing in testing) in a build.gradle(.app) setting?

```
android{
  testOptions{
      something...
  }
}
```

or is there another way?